# merge 2 files in unix using awk based on a part of column

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I have 2 files having data in format :

```
File1 Format : Customer_Key | Customer_DOB 
File2 Format : Customer_ID | Customer_Key | Customer_DOB
```

My target is to compare the fields Customer_DOB which is date in time stamp format YYYYMMDDHH24MISS. But the problem I am facing is I have to compare only date part of DOB field irrespective of time part.
That is , if File1.Customer_DOB is 19900101000000 and File1.Customer_DOB is 19900101122543, these both will be considered as same.

I need to generate an output file which contain the columns where the date mismatches. Output file will be in format :

```
Customer_ID | Customer_Key | File1.Customer_DOB | File2.Customer_DOB
```

Sample Date of File1

```
900899036|899036|19630110000000
900899039|899039|19810701000000
900899044|899044|19900223000000
```

Sample Date of File2

```
899036|1963011122515
2699053|20000101132410
899039|19880501230110
2699052|19890224121014
899044|19900223011214
```

Output File

```
900899039|899039|**19810701000000**|**19880501230110**
```

I have to generate a report where date mismatch is there

I got so many examples to merge the file based on common column but I am getting stucked in my case.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Use the `{}` command to add code tags to your post so its more readable. You find it in the toolbar when you edit your post. Mark text and click command.

Comment: Is a solution _not_ based on `awk` also acceptable?

Comment: Can I assume that for each line in File1 there is exactly one line with a matching Customer_Key in File2?

Comment: @Alfe...actually I tried my best with awk...but any command is fine....Also for every record in File1, there is either no record or only 1 record will be there in File2

Comment: So you want to match the records based on the `Customer_Key`? Some sample input data and the expected outcome would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

So fixed but:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($3!=a[$2]){$3="**"$3"|**"a[$2]"**"};print}' OFS='|' FS='|' f2 f1
```